# jQuery clone() overwriting previously cloned elements

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a form template that I need to copy dynamically to associate with new instances of a popup. I'm using jQuery's clone() method to do so. Whenever I try to create a new instance of the template, the previously created forms' options are erased.

Sample code:
HTML:

```
<div id="template" class="modifyDiv">
    <div class="options">
        <label><input type="radio" class="foo" checked="checked" value="bar" name="displayMode">Foo</label>
        <label><input type="radio" class="blah" value="biz" name="displayMode">Blah</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
popup.create = function() {
    // create popup stuff
    createViewSettings(popup);
}

createTemplate = function(popup) {
...
    var modifyDiv = $("#template").clone(true).removeAttr("id");
    modifyDiv.appendTo($(document.body));
    modifyDiv.data("popup",popup);
    popup.data("settings",modifyDiv);
... }
```

What's happening is this: when I create a new popup the settings are perfect. But when I create a second one, the original "displayMode" checkbox's value becomes undefined.

I've stepped through and the line that seems to cause the issue is:

```
var clone = elem.cloneNode(true)
```

in the clone definition in jquery. I'm using v1.5.1

EDIT: This problem occurs in Chrome 14.0.835.202, but not in IE8
EDIT: This problem occurs when the inputs are radio buttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: Your code is working for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DfBHh/  Is it possible that a different part of your code is causing the issue?

Comment: Hmmm thanks Brian, your example looks just right, even when I revert it to version 1.5.2. I'll update my example to try to get more specific

Comment: I've elaborated on the example. If there's nothing apparent here then I'll dig elsewhere into my code but it looks to me like either one of 2 things is happening: 1) the original settings div is getting modified with the creation of a new settings div, or 2) the checkboxes are unset because there are checkboxes with the same name elsewhere on the page.

Comment: @stinkycheeseman Can you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: @dgilland I'm trying to recreate it but in jsFiddle it works fine. I'll keep digging to see what I can come up with. What's weird is that I know the problem must be in my other code somewhere, but the un-setting of the checkbox happens exactly where I said it did, in the first line of "clone."

Comment: @dgilland here's the exact problem http://fiddle.jshell.net/DfBHh/18/. They're radio buttons, not checkboxes. The checkboxes work fine, as we saw.

Comment: @stinkycheeseman It's the radio `name` attribute being the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [answer](/questions/7823122/jquery-clone-overwriting-previously-cloned-elements/7825161#7825161) was partially correct.  You can only have one radio group with a given name per `<form>`, but you can have as many forms as you want on a page.  Replacing one of your wrapping `<div>` elements with a `<form>` should fix the issue:

```
<div id="template" class="modifyDiv">
    <form class="options">
        <label><input type="radio" class="foo" checked="checked" value="bar" name="displayMode">Foo</label>
        <label><input type="radio" class="blah" value="biz" name="displayMode">Blah</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Live demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DfBHh/19/

Answer (score 0):

This is a dumb question; when you clone a div with radio buttons you have to make sure the new div's radio buttons have a unique name, because only one radio button with a given name can be selected on a given page.